# Mongo Nodejs How can I update index (expiry time) dynamically?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, indexing

How can I update the index and its expiration time inside my nodejs controller dynamically?

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ 
    ...
    status: {
        type: String //active or pending
    },
    confirmationCode: {
        type: String
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date
    }
}, {strict: true, strictQuery: true});
```

```
userSchema.index({ createdAt: 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 2*60, partialFilterExpression: {
        "status": "pending"
    }});
```

How can I include:

```
db.runCommand({
   collMod: "user_log",
   index: {
      keyPattern: { lastAccess: 1 },
      expireAfterSeconds: 3600
   }
})
```

in my nodejs controller:

```
resendConfirmationLink: async (req, res, next) => {
   await User.findOneAndUpdate({_id: userId}, {createdAt: new Date(), ...}, {new: true});
//I cant just run User.runCommand...
}
```